# SQL table Indexes and Spotfire performance

Tags: sql-server, indexing, ssms, spotfire

I have a spotfire project that references several large SQL Server based tables (One has 700,000 rows with 200 columns, another is 80,000,000 rows with 10 columns, a few others that are much smaller by comparison). Currently I use information links with prompts to narrow down the data before loading into spotfire. Still have issues sometimes with RAM usage creeping up and random CPU spikes after data has been loaded.

My questions are **if I add indexes to the SQL tables:**

1. Will the amount of RAM/CPU usage by spotfire get better (lower)?
2. Will it help speed up the initial data load time?
3. Should I even bother?

I'm using SQL Server 2016 and Tibco Spotfire Analyst 7.7.0 (build version 7.7.0.39)

Thanks

Comment: with data tables of these dimensions, you should probably look into aggregating them before they get to Spotfire. many times the analysis "consumers" demand "all the data," but really they only need specific analytics or findings or whatever. I recommend to do more discovery with your end users to determine what, specifically, they need, and design accordingly. this is not really a Spotfire issue; it's a data issue.

Comment: an afterthought: if for some reason that's not feasible (there's no reason it should not be feasible; nobody is going to look at 80 million records individually), do note that every version of Spotfire gets performance enhancements. you will see a bump in performance by upgrading. 7.11 is a good choice because it's the current LTS version.

Answer (score 1):

If you add indexes without logical reason, it actually makes your system slower because indexes constantly update themselves after each INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE. You can ignore my statement if your DB has static data and you won't change the content usually.

You need to understand what parts of your queries consume most of resources, then create indexes accordingly.

Following URLs will help you:

https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/mysql-performance-identifying-long-queries/
https://www.eversql.com/choosing-the-best-indexes-for-mysql-query-optimization/